# Some times when i close the lid of my laptop I get black screen

Tags: 14.04, screen, lenovo

I bought a LENOVO G50-70 59-440027 laptop.
some times I close the lid and when I open it up again I get black screen and the only way to see my screen is to power cycle the laptop.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/248967/laptop-screen-stays-blank-after-lid-is-reopened?rq=1

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

I personally had this issue solved with a driver update (on a laptop with mixed Intel / nVidia graphics; I updated both the Intel and the nVidia drivers).

If this doesn't solve the problem for you or you can't update the drivers for any reason, the best I can give is a better workaround, i.e. once opened the lid to switch to a TTY with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and then to switch back to the `X` environment with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, fixed it by following solution provided by ubuntu faqs.

'INFO: This will not work for 12.04, resume from hibernate work differently in 12.04.'

```
Pull up a Terminal again and run cat /proc/swaps and hopefully you see the path to your swap partition listed there. If not chances are something went wrong in the steps above. Here's my output:
```

Filename Type Size Used Priority
/dev/sda2 partition 2676732 73380 -1

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub & to pull up the boot loader configuration
Look for the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" and make sure it looks like this (using your UUID of course) GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="resume=UUID=41e86209-3802-424b-9a9d-d7683142dab7" and save the file
sudo update-grub and wait for it to finish
gksu gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume & and make sure its contents are resume=UUID=41e86209-3802-424b-9a9d-d7683142dab7 (with your UUID of course in place of mine). Save the file!
sudo update-initramfs -u
Reboot!
```

Answer (score -2):

Update to the latest 16.3 graphics Radeon Crimson. It will work.

http://www.amd.com/en-us/innovations/software-technologies/enhanced-media/radeon-software