# The screen stays dark after I reopen the lid

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, power-management, laptop

I have an e-machines E727 laptop and lubuntu 16.04. I disabled all kind of automatic screen locking and I set it not to suspend when I close the lid. When I close the lid and reopen, I would expect the screen to be back on. However, the screen stays dark. I have to press Ctrl+Alt+F2 and then Ctrl+Alt+F7 to see anything again. Is there a way to fix this?

I tried all of these, without success:

- [Black screen after i close the lid and reopen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162870/black-screen-after-i-close-the-lid-and-reopen)
- https://bytefreaks.net/gnulinux/lubuntu-do-nothing-when-i-close-the-laptops-lid
- https://bytefreaks.net/gnulinux/lubuntu-do-nothing-when-i-close-the-laptops-lid
- [Laptop screen stays blank after lid is reopened](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248967/laptop-screen-stays-blank-after-lid-is-reopened)

Comment: FYI: Lubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (https://lubuntu.me/xenial-5-released/ http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Lubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.  *You also tagged 14.04, all 14.04 LTS is EOL*

Comment: It shows that 1144 packages are supported until April 2021 and 235 packages are no longer supported.

Comment: The base packages (ie. those used by Ubuntu Server/Ubuntu Desktop (Unity 7) are the supported packages, however that does not include 'universe' repository software which is where flavors are found, such as all of LXDE. Your GUI is unsupported if you check the unsupported packages. Ubuntu doesn't want to encourage people using unsupported or past-EOL software, thus you'll not get much support from people associated with Ubuntu projects, flavors, members etc. We of course are happy for people to continue using our software past its supported life, You could use Unity 7 on your supported 16.04.

Comment: Be patient and you may get support from other users, after all this is a *user support* site (*my comments relate more to official policy for project people*)

Comment: I upgraded to 18.04 and the problem is gone, thanks!